# The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace <Page>.g.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am making an app in which i need to use a Custom BasePage from which all other Pages of the app will inherit. I created a new TestProject and did all the following It **worked Perfactly**, But when I Do same thing in MyProject, an error occures

> The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace TestPage.g.cs

Here is code of BaseScreenPage

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class BaseScreenPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private static bool isToShowAgain = true ;
        public static bool isToNavigateToContent;
        public BaseScreenPage() 
        { 

        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) 
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            if (isToNavigateToContent) {
                isToNavigateToContent = false;
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Screens/ContentScreen.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }


         }


    }
}
```

And I am Making Page that is Inheriting from `BaseScreenPage` here is

```
<hyper:BaseScreenPage
    x:Class="MyProject.TestPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:hyper="clr-namespace:MyProject"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</hyper:BaseScreenPage>
```

Also I am doing This in Code of TestPage

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class TestPage : BaseScreenPage
    {
        public TestPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried all the solutions in [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567945/type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist)

Please Suggest some solution

Comment: aren't there any resource dictionaries? the error is only that one?

Comment: no there are no Resource dictionaries. The thing is same code works in a test project

Comment: The error points to auto-generated file `TestPage.g.cs`.. Try to clean and rebuild your solution ?

Comment: I cleaned about a 10 times and when i Build the project same thing happens, Its head scratching situation for me today.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether that's the cause of the issue, but your XAML looks wrong to me. You're declaring the `BasePage` node in the `hyper` XML namespace, but you haven't declared that namespace anywhere. You're missing a declaration:

```
<hyper:BaseScreenPage
    x:Class="MyProject.TestPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:hyper="declareYourNamespaceHere"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
```