# Visual Studio throws errors when attaching to Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

All of a sudden when I try to attach to Unity 5.2 with Visual Studio 2015 I get a bunch of errors as seen in screenshot below. This is the second this has happened this week. Last time I had to create a new project and bring everything over to resolve the issue. Unity plays fine, no errors...but visual studio throws errors when I try to attach. It worked earlier this evening.

[image: Build errors in Visual Studio 2015]

Comment: When these type of errors occur there is some in-compatibility with the `unity` and some of the `dll`'s  you refer in the project.. Just try removing corresponding `dll`s and add it back.. Also clean the project and rebuild it and if possible just search what versions of the in-compatible `dll` can be used with the `unity`.

Comment: Do you have all DLLs you project depends on in the plugins folder and are they all compiled to correct architecture for your editor?

Answer (score 1):

**Few things to consider when project shows error while being fully functional in Unity3D Editor itself:**

- Can you build your project in `Visual Studio` even if errors are shown? If so, there is possiblity that these are just leftovers from Unity3D building your project - *should disappear on first successful build from VS*
- If you can't build your project, have you tried to remove your `Library` folder from project's root folder? In many cases it will fix the problem but will end up in forcing Unity3D to rebuild some of the files it had previously in `Library` folder.
- Have you added any new libraries (`dll`'s) to project? Any chance they might be installed/added in a wrong way? If so, try readding them to project (if it's a classic `dll`) or readd plugin that you have troubles with.

I would leave version incompability as it would end up with errors in Unity3D console. Same with errors with solution per se.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed target framework to Unity 3.5 .net full Base Class Libraries the build errors went away.

[image: Change Target Framework]

I found the solution posted by Nathan Koop here: [Type or namespace name does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567945/type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist)

Comment: I've found that it keeps on reverting to Unity 3.5 Base Class Libraries instead of Full base class. Not sure why.