# Cannot publish website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I read some post about how to speed up websites on asp.net mvc and see one solution - uncheck this

[image]

But now I have trouble. I receiving this error

> C:\Users\j.suhomlin\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f336d68\90ff08c5\App_Web_34z4emv0.0.cs(30,0): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Clients' does not exist in the namespace 'SmartSolutions.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

When I check this option, website publishing well

How I can solve it?

Comment: Did you try to rebuild the solution? Its look like vs losts reference to "Clients" namespace.

Comment: Yes, I tried:( @daniell89

Comment: so try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35440678/5358389