# VS 2015 CS0234 False Error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

Other Resources Checked/ Ideas tried

- [Don't understand why we're getting error CS0234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419905/dont-understand-why-were-getting-error-cs0234)
- [Type or namespace name does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567945/type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist)
- Cleaning the solution then rebuilding.
- Removing the obj and bin folders completely for both projects.

Setup

- Visual Studio 2015 update 3
- .net 4.5

I currently have a solution with 2 projects. 1 project has a direct reference to the other project, they are both .net 4.5. For simplicity, I will call the project that is being referenced 'A', and the project that is referencing A - 'B'.

While developing in B I have full IntelliSense on classes within A. As soon as I build the solution, project A builds successfully, but project B has several errors as such:

> The type or namespace name 'x' does not exist in the namespace
>   'projectName' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

When I double click the error to navigate to the file I see the error on the 'using' statement for about 1 second, then it disappears along with the error from the error list. I can continue clicking through the entire error list until the error list is empty, but as soon as I rebuild the errors reappear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify if project B is referencing other dll files that use a higher Framework version than 4.5, also, I have experienced this problem due to some Nuget packages that had to be added in every project that referenced the original one using the package.

Comment: This was the issue. One project was referencing 4.6.2 NuGet reference. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: Likewise.  Added a new DLL Project to solution and didn't notice it defaulted to 4.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at your Project Dependencies.  To do this:
Right Click on your Solution and select Properties
Then on the left side of the screen select 'Project Dependencies'
Make sure that Project 'B' depends on Project 'A'.

This will assure that the projects are being built in the correct order.  It should already be set this way, but sometimes Visual Studio doesn't set the dependencies up correctly.

Also, make sure that you don't have any references to Project 'A' in Project 'B'.  That would create a circular dependency and give you no end of grief.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a file reference or a project reference. If its a file reference (ie you pointed at the output dll of project A) then you need to ensure that the project dependencies say that B depends on A so that they get built in the correct order