# Type Name Web Does not Exist in Type Name System

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I created an MVC project in Visual Studio 2015 and when I compiled it I got this error:

> Type name 'Web' does not exist in the type name 'System'

This was in the autogenerated models AccountViewModel and ManageViewModel. I'm surprised to see that there's an error considering that A: These are autogenerated and B: My other very similar projects compiled without this issue.

The code in which it is referencing is:

```
public class SendCodeViewModel
{
    public string SelectedProvider { get; set; }
    public ICollection<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> Providers { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ConfigureTwoFactorViewModel
{
    public string SelectedProvider { get; set; }
    public ICollection<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> Providers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Either 1 - your project does not have the Mvc NuGet package referenced or 2 - the error is not from one of those lines but somewhere else which can happen if you are referencing using a partial namespace like omitting `System`. Alternatively your default namespace might be System or something like that. Or 3 - do you have a type defined named System, in that case prefix the namespace with global like so `global::System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7155510/3709746

Comment: Igor you're right, I just realized I can't use the type "System" as a class, gotta rename it.