# Can't build project with VS2015

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with my project (it worked before) I did a clean checkout from the teamserver... and now I can't build. But VS shows me no error:

[image]

but in the output I can see some errors

[image]

But these files are fine:

[image]

no errors... all libs are fine.

Any idea where to search for the problem?

PS: it looks for me like the build script cant find packages... but I am not really sure.

I also checked my csproj file

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

the file is present.

Comment: have you tried creating a new simple project to see if it works? if it works, check your code again.

Comment: @active92 yes, I can build another projects... it should be something with this project...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type or namespace name does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567945/type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist)

Comment: Always post error message as text. Simply looking for duplicates may solve your problem (if they don't then mention them to exclude such cases, otherwise question is too broad as you may see).

Comment: @Fribu there are way too many possibilities. Try running your visual studio as admin.

Comment: @active92 no effect :(