# Visual Studio 2017 New project build gives "The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: visual-studio

Whenever I open a new project and simply build it the output box gives me about 7 of these errors. Same thing over and over just different error code. Please help solve my problem.

Comment: First thing is to make sure you're using the latest updates/patches for VS2017 as the base version is very buggy. Another common bug that resembles this is easily fixed by simply closing Visual Studio and re-opening it. Have you done both of these?

Comment: Here: [Type or namespace does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567945/type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist)

Comment: Very likely your machine has some problem connecting to NuGet.org for VS to restore the packages.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I decided it was easier for me to just use Visual Studio Code for the class I was taking.