# The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace after executing a cleanup

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This problem is making me officially crazy, until now everything was working correctly, now the program is showing a lot of monstrous errors.

In practice, I clicked with the right mouse button on the project and I selected "Clean", when I clicked "Compile" I got so many errors like:

The type or namespace does not exist in the namespace

I looked for the error on the internet and I found these:

[Type or namespace name does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567945/type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist)

but it did not help me, also I'm working with 5 projects, and everyone has set up version as 4.6.1

Comment: If (after issuing a `Clean`) you inspect the references of your projects, are any shown as missing? If so, are they other projects within the same solution or general assemblies?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever in the reference tab there is no warning or errors

Comment: Then we need a set of steps from starting with an open instance of VS with no solution loaded to getting to this reload problem that *demonstrates* the issue. Odds are *very* high that, in attempting to create this [mcve] you'll realise what the issue is.

Comment: I understand, but what I can tell you is that I had a completely functional program and I just clicked "Clean", then it happened a disaster, I do not know how to recreate the bug for everyone, otherwise I would be able to solve it, I do not know if you understand

Comment: Yes, but without the sequence, it's "guess what's wrong with my setup" and it's unlikely that someone will be able to. I see someone has offered a random suggestion as an answer, but odds are low. This is debugging technique (of compile time rather than runtime) skills that you *need* to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens after `Clean` when you haven't set your  `Solution Build Sequence` properly.

**If missing reference is in same solution**

Two possible fixed

> Try `Building` each project those are referenced with in other
>   projects individually.

Or

> Make a proper build sequence of projects in your solutions..

Comment: Glad to know it helped :)