# The type or namespace does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, namespaces

I am unable to build my project because it thinks a namespace doesn't exist.

There is no red line in the editor, and I can navigate to the types in that namespace by hitting F12 on the type.

Why is this incorrect error msg coming through?

I have tried cleaning/building, and rebuilding the project, as well as restarting VS.

[image]

Comment: I think you are missing the reference on the project, make a double check, clean and build again your project.

Comment: More often the issue is the package vs core package. Since you whited out the name of the package, you will need to see if there is a core package that needs to be installed before these addons packages will function correctly.

Comment: I find [Type or namespace name does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567945/type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist). It suggests that you can use set the same framework for all projects to solve the problem. You can have a try.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this helps: try to **unload the project and load it again**.
Right cklick on the Project in Project Explorer and unload this.
here example in [German Context Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHts9.png)

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan said try unload and load the project.

It looks like the issue is happening in your testing project. Try to delete and re-add the corresponding references.