# Mysterious name resolution differences between legacy and SDK-style C# projects

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I encountered this confusing names-resolution problem while trying to convert legacy solution with .NET 4.6.1 projects to the new SDK-style project formats. I was able to create a minimal repro solution `LegacyVsSdkStyleProjectNameResolution`, which is on GitHub here:

https://github.com/PaloMraz/LegacyVsSdkStyleProjectNameResolution.git

The solution contains:

- 3 legacy projects targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 residing in the „Legacy“ solution folder; the project names start with „Legacy.“).
- 3 SDK-style projects targeting .NET residing in the „Sdk“ solution folder; the project names start with „Sdk.“.

(Please forgive me the non-intuitive assembly / namespace / class names – I could not use the original names and was not able to devise something more feasible).

The dependencies are shown in this image:

[image: CodeMap]

The problem is, the `Legacy.Common.Configuration` project successfuly compiles with this `Bundle` class declaration:

```
using Legacy.Common.Data;

namespace Legacy.Common.Configuration
{
  public class Bundle
  {
    public Person Person { get; set; }
  }
}
```

But the `Sdk.Common.Configuration` produces compilation error `CS0118` ('Person' is a namespace but is used like a type):

```
using Sdk.Common.Data;

namespace Sdk.Common.Configuration
{
  public class Bundle
  {
    public Person Person { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Can anybody please explain, why the C# compiler in the `Sdk.Common.Configuration` project resolves the `Person` type symbol incorrectly to namespace `Sdk.Common.Person`, but in the `Legacy.Common.Configuration` it resolves it correctly to `Legacy.Common.Data.Person` class?

Comment: Nice question: good mcve, good downloadable repro. Very impressed, +1

Comment: i'm curios what was the tool used for this drawing please ? excellent

Comment: The drwaing is the standard Visual Studio Code Map tooling - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SDK-style projects, a project will automatically inherit all of the things that its dependencies depend on. In legacy projects this had to be done manually, with the tooling inserting explicit references to all of the things that a new dependency depended on.

So in your SDK-style project, Sdk.Common.Configuration is inheriting a reference to Sdk.Common.Person.Management, by virtue of the fact that it references Sdk.Common.Data.

---

Sdk.Common.Person.Management defines the namespace Sdk.Common.Person:

```
namespace Sdk.Common.Person.Management
{
  ...
}
```

While Sdk.Common.Data defines the class Sdk.Common.Data.Person.:

```
namespace Sdk.Common.Data
{
  public class Person
  {
  }
}
```

Sdk.Common.Configuration then does this:

```
using Sdk.Common.Data;

namespace Sdk.Common.Configuration
{
  public class Bundle
  {
    public Person Person { get; set; }
  }
}
```

There, the compiler searches the namespace `Sdk.Common.Configuration` (and Sdk.Common, and Sdk) for `Person` *before* it considers that `using`. It finds `Sdk.Common.Person` which is a namespace, and complains because you're using a namespace as a type.

If you include the `using` inside the namespace, this order flips, and the compiler will search `Sdk.Common.Data` *first*, and find the `Sdk.Common.Data.Person` class:

```
namespace Sdk.Common.Configuration
{
  using Sdk.Common.Data;

  public class Bundle
  {
    public Person Person { get; set; }
  }
}
```

[See this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151560/1086121).

---

As for how to solve this, first off don't define a class and a namespace with the same name. If you can't avoid this, you can either change the location of the `using` as shown above, or use the fully-qualified name of the `Person` class.

If you want to mirror the legacy behaviour of Sdk.Common.Data's references not being inherited by Sdk.Common.Configuration, use `PrivateAsserts="All"` on the `ProjectReference` which includes Sdk.Common.Person.Management.

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Sdk.Common.Person.Management\Sdk.Common.Person.Management.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

This states that Sdk.Common.Person.Management is a private dependency, which isn't inherited by anything which references Sdk.Common.Data.